# Opencv VideoWriter tempfile

Tags: python, temporary-files, opencv

I am attempting to write a list of images to an mp4 video. When I use VideoWriter to a local mp4 filepath, this code works perfectly and my mp4 file is saved to disk.

However, I need to do this operation in a server, using a tempfile, to then send to other places. To test using a tempfile, I simply change the VideoWriter filename to the file_out.name (via NamedTemporaryFile) and copy to disk to verify that it worked correctly. The output I get is an equally sized mp4 file, but it can't be opened by any video player - so something must be wrong with the file.

```
file_out = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.mp4')

video = cv2.VideoWriter(file_out.name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1'),20,(width,height))

for i in range(len(images)):
    video.write(np.asarray(images[i]))

shutil.copy(file_out.name, '/path/to/test_output.mp4')
```

What could be going on so that VideoWriter isn't able to correctly write to my tempfile?

P.S. My first attempt was writing VideoWriter to a BytesIO to then send directly over http - that didn't work so I regressed to tempfile.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

VideoWriter output MUST be released for output of copied file to be valid.

```
video.release()
```

This fixes the problem.